# Selenium: test if element contains some text

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-ide

With Selenium IDE, how can I test if an element's inner text contains a specific string? For example:

```
<p id="fred">abcde</p>
'id=fred' contains "bcd" = true)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [Selenium-IDE documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#verifying-page-elements) is helpful in this situation.

The command you are looking for is `assertText`, the locator would be `id=fred` and the text for example `*bcd*`.

Comment: even though I got it slightly before you I'll give you the answer points.

Comment: @Slanec is there any thing, that i can search the text and click on it?

Comment: The key bit of the documentation is further down in [Matching Text Patterns](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#matching-text-patterns) which talks about the wildcards.

Comment: Wildcards don't seem to work anymore (in 2023)

Answer (score 5):

It can be done with a simple wildcard:

```
verifyText
id="fred"
*bcd*
```

See [selenium IDE Doc](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#globbing-patterns)

Comment: Oh. Right at the same moment.

Comment: Yes. Less than a minute too slow. Hehe

Answer (score 4):

You can also use:

```
assertElementPresent
css=p#fred:contains('bcd')
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what I needed: `css=p:contains('foo')`. However, I'm told that it's deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with XPath:

Command: **verify element present**

Target: **xpath=//div[@id='fred' and contains(.,'bcd')]**

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use jQuery if so try something like

```
$("p#fred:contains('bcd')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```

Comment: how would this be possible with selenium IDE?

Answer (score 0):

It seems regular expressions might work:

```
"The simplest character set is a character. The regular expression "the" contains three
character sets: "t," "h" and "e". It will match any line with the string "the" inside it.
This would also match the word "other". "
```

(From site: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html)

If you are using visual studio there is functionality for evaluating strings with regular expressions of ALL kinds (not just contains):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex.IsMatch("YourInnerText", @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

The expression I posted will check if the string contains ONLY letters.

Your regular expression would then according to my link be "bcd" or some string you construct at runtime. Or:

```
Regex.IsMatch("YourInnerText", @"bcd");
```

(Something like that anyway)

Hope it helped.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the command `assertTextPresent` or `verifyText`

Comment: yes but I was trying to get a partial match, not full. Also it's not just that command that can be used.