# verifyText using *text* instead of verifyTextPresent (deprecated)

Tags: selenium, text, wildcard, selenium-ide, verify

I'm kind of new to selenium IDE and automated test and I don't know much about programming languages. I have a question concerning verifyText command as verifyTextPresent is deprecated. If I put the target word/text in * * will it work as if I was using verifyTextPresent? Could waitForText work?

I am trying to verify that the search function of a website is working as expected. I search the word "client" and I want to verify that the word is present in the results.

```
    clickAndWait   css=div.cf-tooltip-text   
    type           id=edit-global-search             client
    clickAndWait   id=edit-submit-global-search
    verifyText     id=content-column                 *client*
```

This works, but in the Log I can not understand what it really does. Also if I try the word on its own "client" I get an error which I understand because it compares it to the text of the whole column. I also tried to put an irrelevant word between asterisks such as *youwillnotfindthetext* (just to make sure that everything between asterisks will pass the test) and there I had an error too.

So it seems to be working somehow but I want to ask some of you expert guys.

Thanks

Comment: @Alex..Glad that you have found my answer informative.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a * in starting and ending means it will look for the `inner text` containing in the specific element. If a text is present as you given in the script it will return a pass. If the text u specified in the script is not present, it will throw an error. That's what happens when you put *youwillnotfindthetext* in between the *.
Check this link [Selenium: test if element contains some text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922054/selenium-test-if-element-contains-some-text)