# How to check whether the element text contains some text with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

[Selenium: test if element contains some text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922054/selenium-test-if-element-contains-some-text)

It is possible to do in selenium IDE but I don't know how to do it with python and selenium.
I want to set a waiting that wait until that element contains part of the specified text. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait for element like this :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'someid')))
```

extract the text like this :

```
actual_text = element.text
```

check whether it contains expected text or not like this:

```
self.assertIn('expected_string_here', actual_text)
```

or like this :

```
print expected_string_here == actual_text
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(By.ID, 'your_element_id', "The_text_you_are_looking_for"))
```

The element can be located by class name, css_selector, xpath etc.
The `By.ID` and the element locator should be updated accordingly

Comment: hi thanks for your reply but this method seems only work for the expected text exactly equal to the element text.
But my question is:
if the element text is "abcde", 
can I use "wait" to see whether the element text contains "abc"

Comment: Did you try this? This method should match condition of text in (contains) that web element, not just equals.